# VBA ADO reference User-Defined error

Tags: python, vba, excel, adodb

little background on what I'm trying to accomplish I'm writing a vba script that executes within my Python code to query SQL. I've been stuck and doing research on this ADO.Recordset that keeps giving me a 'User-defined error' I've added all of the required references(to my knowledge)to the code being called out by GUID.

Please see code below.

```
import pyodbc
import os
import win32com.client as win32
import comtypes, comtypes.client

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
ss = xl.Workbooks.Add()
sh = ss.ActiveSheet

xlmodule = ss.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

sCode = '''Sub Download_Standard_BOM()
'Initializes variables
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As Object: Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String


    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Network Library=dbmssocn;Password=******;User ID=******;Initial Catalog=*****;Data Source=************;"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}", 2, 3

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 2, 3

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 2, 3

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 2, 3

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{00000600-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}", 2, 3

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{00025E01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 2, 3

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{00000300-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}", 2, 3

    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM car_search WHERE search_id = 9999999"

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub'''

xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)
xl.Run ('Download_Standard_BOM')
```

I appreciate all of the help you guys provide!

Comment: `CurrentProject.Connection` is an Access thing: it doesn't exist in Excel VBA  It's not clear what that's doing there, since you're setting `cn` to that (but before declaring it) and then later setting `cn` again...

Comment: Ah, thank you Tim I have removed that from the program but still unfortunately receiving the error pertaining to ADODB.Recordset

Comment: Unrelated, but you should add the project references if they're not present, in a dedicated procedure, *before* you open a connection (so as to have the connection opened only as long as you need it) - that said you're late-binding ADODB, so what are these GUIDs for anyway?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - only the Connection is late-bound.  It would be better to use late binding throughout, and skip adding the references altogether.  I'd rather put this code in a separate xlam instead, and have that perform the query and dump the results to the sheet, *unless* this needs to be run again later.

Comment: `rst.Open StrQuery, cnn` should be `rst.Open StrQuery, cn` (other lines have same issue)

Comment: Mat, I apologize I'm very new with using VB. I'm doing some research on early binding vs late binding to better educate myself on that for the code(Little lost currently). Also, I'm calling out the GUIDS for the required references for ADODB I believe? Sorry I'm confusing myself even more at this point haha. How would I add the project references  in a dedicated procedure?

Comment: This line is throwing the error 'Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use Python directly to connect to SQL Server (no COM interface) and output data into csv or Excel format (the latter using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), Python's data analysis package):

Below is the CSV and ODBC DRIVER approach:

```
import pyodbc
import csv

constr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=database;' \
         'Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=username;PWD=password'
conn = pyodbc.connect(constr)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM car_search WHERE search_id = 9999999")

with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])   # COLUMNS
    for row in cur.fetchall():        
        writer.writerow(row)                           # DATA ROWS

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Below is the pandas (using `read_sql`, `to_csv`, `to_excel`) and OLEDB PROVIDER approach:

```
import adodbapi
import pandas as pd

constr = 'PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=database;' \
         'Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=yes;' \ 
         'User ID=username;Password=password'    
conn = adodbapi.connect(constr)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM car_search WHERE search_id = 9999999", conn)
df.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False)
df.to_excel('Output.xlsx', index=False)

conn.close()
```

Of course, ODBC/OLEDB can be swapped for either, aligning to corresponding module (`pyodbc`/`pypyodbc` vs `adodbapi`).

Comment: That is the route that I have gone now thank you very much Parfait for this detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any references if you use late binding:

```
sCode = '''Sub Download_Standard_BOM()
'Initializes variables


Dim cnn As Object: Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rst As Object: Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String


    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Network Library=dbmssocn;Password=******;" & _
      "User ID=******;Initial Catalog=*****;Data Source=************;"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM car_search WHERE search_id = 9999999"

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub'''
```